# Error con los submenús

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
/* Menu */

#menu ul {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #3d4449;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-family: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.075em;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu ul a,
#menu ul span {
  border-bottom: 0;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0.625em 0;
}

#menu ul a:hover,
#menu ul span:hover {
  color: #f56a6a;
}

#menu ul a.opener,
#menu ul span.opener {
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul a.opener:before,
#menu ul span.opener:before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none !important;
}

#menu ul a.opener:before,
#menu ul span.opener:before {
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -ms-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: #9fa3a6;
  content: '\f078';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#menu ul a.opener:hover:before,
#menu ul span.opener:hover:before {
  color: #f56a6a;
}

#menu ul a.opener.active+ul,
#menu ul span.opener.active+ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul a.opener.active:before,
#menu ul span.opener.active:before {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

#menu>ul>li {
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(210, 215, 217, 0.75);
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

#menu>ul>li>ul {
  color: #9fa3a6;
  display: none;
  margin: 0.5em 0 1.5em 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

#menu>ul>li>ul a,
#menu>ul>li>ul span {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#menu>ul>li>ul>li {
  margin: 0.125em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0.125em 0 0 0;
}

#menu>ul>li:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <header class="major">
    <h2>SPORTS</h2>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">SOCCER</a></li>
    <li><a href="generic.php">Generic</a></li>
    <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
    <li>

      <span class="opener">SOCCER</span>
      <span class="opener">EUROPE</span>
      <span class="opener">TOP COUNTRIES</span>
      <span class="opener">ENGLAND</span>

      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
      <label for="btn-menu">PREMIER LEAGUE</label>
      <?php include('\premier league.php');?>
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
      <label for="btn-menu">CHAMPIONSHIP</label>
      <?php include('\premier league.php');?>
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
      <label for="btn-menu">LEAGUE ONE</label>
      <?php include('\league one.php');?>
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
      <label for="btn-menu">LEAGUE TWO</label>
      <?php include('\league two.php');?>
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
      <label for="btn-menu">NATIONAL LEAGUE</label>
      <?php include('\national league.php');?>
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
      <label for="btn-menu">FOOTBALL LEAGUE TROPHY</label>
      <li><a>TURKEY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SCOTLAND</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SPAIN</a></li>
      <span class="opener">NORTH AMERICA</span>
      <span class="opener">SOUTH AMERICA</span>
      <span class="opener">AFRICA</spa
      <span class="opener">ASIA</span>
      <span class="opener">OCEANIA</span>
      <span class="opener">WORLD</span>
```

Que me genera algo así:

[image: Menu en pagina web]

Como se puede ver, las tablas me salen mal.  Lo que yo quiero es que a la hora de seleccionar PREMIER LEAGUE me salga la tabla y no que salga sin seleccionar nada. Y tengo otro problema que los submenús no me funcionan...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PREMIER LEAGUE</title>
</head>
<body>
```

connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>


    
        PREMIER LEAGUE 2017/18
    
    
        Team
        Played
        Win
        Draw
        Loss
        Goals
        Diff
        Points

```
</body>
```

adjunto el codigo de la tabla.

Comment: Hola Imanol, deberías añadir algo más de detalle en la pregunta (p.e. cómo no funcionan los submenús). Además, sería importante saber cómo funciona “premier league.php”. Esto realmente no parece un problema de PHP sino de CSS y JavaScript y quizás sería mejor ver el código generado antes que el código PHP que lo genera. Lee [ask] y [mcve] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar esta pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro he incluido el .css el apartado del menú. Un saludo :)

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro tambien he añadido al principio del .css donde el menu la siguiente linea... pero aun así me sigue saliendo mal... #menu input [type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  display:none;
  }

Comment: Gracias por añadir más información a la pregunta. La he actualizado un poco para que sea más fácil de leer (recortar la imagen para enfocarse en el problema) y ver el código (aunque como es PHP y no el HTML generado, no se va a ver del todo bien). Pero me imagino que el HTML que falta (el generado por "premier league.php") es una tabla simple y se puede simular.

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro si eso es, como ves en la imagen es una tabla simple solo que lo tengo guardado en otra carpeta aunque si quieres mando el codido de la tabla pero lo que has dicho es una tabla muy simple como se ve en la imagen

Comment: Es esencial que añadas el código (o parte de él). y que también añadas los estilos que se aplican a esa tabla. Sin tener toda la información es muy difícil (si no imposible) poder ayudarte. Lee sobre [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](/help/mcve) donde encontrarás consejos y recomendaciones a la hora de añadir código y luego edita tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro añadi la tabla del como seria